# Existence of a sub-sequence of non-converge sequence that $|x_{p_n}-L|>\epsilon$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence that does not converge and let L be a real
>   number. Prove that there exist $\epsilon >0$ and a sub-sequence
>   $\{x_{p_n}\}$ of $\{x_n\}$ such that $|x_{p_n}-L|>\epsilon$ for all n.

I don't have any idea on how to prove this. Any advice and suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The sequence itself is a subsequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $(x_n)$ does not converge to $L$ there is $\epsilon >0$ such that

$|x_n-L|> \epsilon$ for infinitely many n.

Now, its your turn.

Answer (score 1):

Simply negate the fact that $x_n$ converges, ie negate :

$$\exists L\in \Bbb R, \forall \epsilon \gt 0, \exists N\in\Bbb N, \forall n\ge N, |x_n-L|\le \epsilon $$

Which gives you :

$$\forall L\in \Bbb R, \exists \epsilon \gt 0, \forall N\in\Bbb N, \exists n\ge N, |x_n-L|\gt \epsilon $$

And this lets you recursively construct the sequence you're looking for.